# Asp.net loading additional user data

Tags: asp.net, session

I am wanting to know when is the earliest point I can load additional user specific data like permissions into a session object right after login. I am using the membership provider but the data to be loaded is from a custom table. Session start is too late and I have tried the master page. 
I'm also wondering where to put that logic to load the additional data. 
I know it would be right after the user is authenticated but where? Global, login page, master page, default page etc.
Any advice would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by the earliest? The earliest is obviously right after the user is authenticated and the authentication cookie has been set.

Comment: I know it's after the user has been authenticated. Where is the best place to put that logic to load the additional data? Global, login page, masterpage etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earliest is obviously right after the user is authenticated. In other words, you should do it immediately your database call to confirm user credentials is successful.

The exact point it's difficult to tell without seeing your code. You may have user authentication logic on your login page (not a good architecture but it's quite common to see this) or you may have the logic on a business layer or a data access layer. You didn't show a piece of code as to tell you where makes more sense for you to have it but it's definitely within the login page or a call to another class made from the login page.

It is definitely not MasterPage or Global.asax